# Google one tab login and keycloak integration

Tags: java, backend, keycloak, google-one-tap

I want to integrate Google one tab login to our App but we are using the Keycloak as an SSO server.

Scenario:

In Google one tab login, after the user successfully logged in to Google, the font-end app receives an Idtoken as a part of the response from Google then our front sends that token to the backend server.
Backend after verifying the IdToken, first register the user in Keycloak and then return an access token (that is generated by Keyclaok) to the user.

The question is:

How can I get a token for the user that is registered from Google IdToken, because this type of user doesn't have a password then it's not possible to use it that way?